# Break is not activated inside a for loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, break, enumerate

I want to print the first 10 key-value pairs from the dictionary word_index and I wrote this code:

```
for key, value in enumerate(word_index):
    count = 0
    if count <10:
        print(f'key {key} : value: {value}')
        count = count + 1
    else:
        break
```

[image]

As you can see the `break` is not activated.  Why is that?  What I should change in the code?

Comment: You're setting `count` to zero each turn through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of count before the for loop. It is reset to 0 at each iteration.

As a side note (I don't have enough reputation to comment) the for loop is probably not doing what you want. You named your variables `key` and `value`, which makes me believe that you want to iterate over the entries (key and value pairs) of the dictionary. To achieve that you should write:

```
for k,v in word_index.items():
  // omitted
```

What `enumerate()` does is to return an index that starts from 0 and it is incremented at each iteration. So the in your code, `key` is actually an index and `value` is the dictionary's key!

If you actually wanted to iterate over the keys and associate an index to each key, you should rename your variable to something more correct, for example `index` and `key`.

I recommend to spend some time studying Python, it will save you lots of debugging time.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `count` outside the for loop.

```
count=0
 #intialize count here
for key, value in enumerate(word_index):
if count <10:
    print(f'key {key} : value: {value}')
    count = count + 1
else:
    break
```